# Android progressbar style

Tags: android

I have 3 issues on my ProgressBar. First of all, I want to set the ProgressBar to be using the old yellow style with huge bar. Then, I want to set the color of the ProgressBar. Lastly, I want to set the margin of the ProgressBar. My code is as follow

```
ProgressBar statusPB = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
                    statusPB.setId(300 + i);
                    statusPB.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    statusPB.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#D69E29"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(160, 80);
                    params.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0);
                    statusPB.setLayoutParams(params);
                    tr.addView(statusPB);
```

All three of them are not working. Changing `android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge` to `android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal` will create the new small progressbar with blue color. Setting the color using setColrFilter is not working either.

Need some help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better of create a custom progress bar in drawable, and set what you need:

custom_progressbar.xml

```
<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape >
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#F1C40F"
                android:centerColor="#F1C40F"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#F1C40F"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:gravity="right">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#56616D"
                android:centerColor="#56616D"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#56616D"
                android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Define a style in styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomProgressBarHorizontal" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progressbar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">4dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">4dip</item>
</style>
```

And then use it:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="@style/CustomProgressBarHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: how do I set to use custom style programmatically?

Comment: If there isn't a good reason I wouldn't try to set style from code.
You can try something like:

progressBar = new ProgressBar(yourActivity, null, android.R.attr.someStyle);

Comment: Well.. the reason is I will be generating the ProgressBar from the codes. There will be more than one ProgressBar. Does android.R.attr.someStyle work for custom style?

Comment: I didn't try it, I've always used a style set in XML.

Comment: I tried your style, but changing the progress, doesn't seem to change the color. I have the background to #737373 and progress to #D69E29. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you set the style in the progress bar XML? this code is working in numerous apps.

Comment: Yup, I did. <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/pbStatus"
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="27dp"
                        style="@style/CustomProgressBarHorizontal"
                        android:progress="25"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

Comment: Try it like this:

Drawable customDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(
     R.drawable.custom_progressbar);

   // set the drawable as progress drawavle
   statusPB.setProgressDrawable(customDrawable);

Comment: I am able to get the CustomProgressBar to work, but the issue now is when I set the progress, the color is not changing.

Comment: What color isn't changing?

Comment: I changed the custom_progressbar.xml file, background to grey and progress to yellow. But when I set my progressbar progress to 50, the colour remains grey.

Comment: got it to work now... for the custom_progressbar.xml file, i was using selector instead of layer-list

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:

ProgressBar statusPB = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);

            Drawable drawable = getResoures().getDrawable(R.drawable.a);
                drawable.setBounds(0,0,drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

                   statusPB .setProgressDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar)
                    statusPB.setId(300 + i);
                    statusPB.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    statusPB.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#D69E29"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(160, 80);
                    params.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0);
                    statusPB.setLayoutParams(params);
                    tr.addView(statusPB);
```

Comment: getDrawable requires API level 21, but my min API is only 15 :(

Comment: getResoures().getDrawable